# How to return an object and not a string with PHP curl request

Tags: php, json, object, curl

I am attempting to request data from a url and am having success for most endpoints except for one. Throughout my troubleshooting, I can retrieve the text and display it in the browser, however, when I try to store it as an object, I get nothing.  It actually still stores as a string.  I would like to iterate through the object so that I can run calculations on the contents.

Is it because the JSON string is malformed?  If so, how do I correct?  I have tried a variety of solutions with no success.

Important to note that gzip is required, for that reason I have included 'ob_gzhandler'.  the contents only echos when I use gzhandler.

THE ECHOS IN THE FUNCTION ARE FOR TROUBLESHOOTING PURPOSES.  THEY ILLUSTRATE WHERE STRINGS ARE BEING PRODUCED AND NOT OBJECTS.

```
function CallAPI_oanda_v20($instruments)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    $url = 'https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v3/instruments/'.$instruments.'/positionBook';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET,TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
          'Content-Type: application/json',
          'Authorization: <USE MY API KEY>')); 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo gettype($response); //returns "string"
    $json = json_decode($response, true);
    echo gettype($json); //returns "NULL"
    curl_close($ch);
    return $json;
}


$call = CallAPI_oanda_v20("GBP_USD");

ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
//$output = ob_get_contents();
echo $call->positionBook; //returns an error:Trying to get property 'positionBook' of non-object
echo gettype($output); //THIS WILL RETURN "string".

$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($output, TRUE)),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
    if(is_array($val)) {
        echo "$key:\n";
    } else {
        echo "$key => $val\n";
    }
}
```

In order to troubleshoot that the call is correct, I echo the contents by graying out the following line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```

Here is the json string that prints:

```
{"positionBook":{"instrument":"GBP_USD","time":"2019-09-02T00:00:00Z","unixTime":"1567382400","price":"1.21584","bucketWidth":"0.00050","buckets":[{"price":"1.19950","longCountPercent":"0.0189","shortCountPercent":"0.0189"},{"price":"1.20000","longCountPercent":"0.0000","shortCountPercent":"0.0189"},{"price":"1.20100","longCountPercent":"0.0000","shortCountPercent":"0.0189"},{"price":"1.20150","longCountPercent":"0.0000","shortCountPercent":"0.0757"}]}}
```

Comment: Not really sure what your question actually is. What issue are you actually facing? The JSON appears to be valid, `$call` should in theory be an object.

Comment: The JSON is valid. Have you tried `echo $call->positionBook;`? If that doesn't work, what about just `echo $call;`?

Comment: `ob_get_contents` returns a string, instead just use `$call`, which has your object

Comment: Your function returns a value; it doesn’t print anything for ob_start to capture

Comment: What Tim said, and once you're using $call (as per Lawrence' comment), don't decode it a second time.

Comment: @Nick - I tried both options, I get nothing when I ```echo $call``` and when I ``` echo $call->positionBook``` I get "Notice: Trying to get property 'positionBook' of non-object"

@LawrenceCherone - I removed ```ob_get_contents``` and but it still shows $call as a string.

Overall it doesn't seem like the function is returning an object.

Comment: It sounds like the `json_decode` is failing, have you tried `echo json_last_error_msg();`?

Comment: @Nick - I wasn't familiar with that function.  When I run it, I get: ```Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded```.  When I look for a solution to this error I found a potential area to explore and updated the code to be: ```$json = preg_replace('/[[:cntrl:]]/', '', $response);
    $json = json_decode($json, true);```.  This then gave me this error:```Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded```

Comment: @user1636985 sounds like progress... try cutting and pasting the raw string into jsonlint.com, that's also a good place to check your JSON

Comment: @Nick - thanks for the tip.  Just checked the JSON and it came back clean. (unfortunately).  I'll keep digging into this area.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
$output = ob_get_contents();
echo gettype($output); //THIS WILL RETURN "string".
```

This is exactly what you expect. The output buffer is just a big string that is appended to whenever you write to it. When you gettype($output) you're just getting the output of that buffer, which is nothing to do with any of your other code.

As you're not actually writing anything to said buffer, it will be an empty string.

You're not actually using the result of your function ($call) anywhere. You should be passing it to your recursive array iterator. In your top function you probably want to add TRUE as the second argument to json_decode so it's fully array based.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED. I was improperly decoding the gzip string.

```
$response = gzdecode($response);
```

This was the key, along with removing:

```
ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
$output = ob_get_contents();
```

Here is the solved piece of code:

````
{
    $curl = curl_init();
    $url = 'https://api-fxtrade.oanda.com/v3/instruments/'.$instruments.'/positionBook';
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET,TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
          'Content-Type: application/json',
          'Authorization: <USE MY API KEY>')); 
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $response = gzdecode($response);
    $json = json_decode($response, true);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $json;
}


$call = CallAPI_oanda_v20("GBP_USD");
echo '<pre>';
print_r($call);
echo '<pre>';```
````